# How to determine registry access of a user via RSOP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, registry

I have some clients that use my software, however they are having some issues with registry access, they are running Windows Server 2008, I was wondering if it is possible to use the RSOP tool to determine the individuals registry privileges? or am I barking up the completely wrong tree?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Are they running your software on the server? How do they access your software? What privileges do they have? RSOP will show the result of the various GPOs that affect the user and if you examine those GPOs, you should be able to find which of them prevent your users accessing the (server? workstation?) registry. More info required.